# Getting slow default warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I get these warnings, every time my app opens from a new state... but I think this is from when the app opens for the first time, it copies the sqlite database.

```
WARNING: Slow defaults initialization - setup took 0.027397 seconds
WARNING: Slow defaults access for key Internal took 0.094897 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000
```

Below is the copy code:

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {


    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];

    if (success) {

        success = [fileManager contentsEqualAtPath:defaultDBPath andPath:dbPath];
        if (!success) {
            BOOL isE = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:dbPath error:&error];
            if (!isE) 
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to remove corrupt database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

        }

    }

    if(!success) {

        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

    }
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath
{
    //Search for standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    //First Param = Searching the documents directory
    //Second Param = Searching the Users directory and not the System
    //Expand any tildes and identify home directories.

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //NSLog(@"dbpath : %@",documentsDir);
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
}
```

How do I prevent my app from giving me these warnings? Is this the normal method when copying a database for SQLite? I know that the database is only being copied once in a while, but i really don't like seeing warnings in the log.

Comment: I have been getting these warnings also, however the app that I get these errors on is incredibly simple and shouldn't provide a slow startup. It is 10 views.

Comment: @Kevin My app is also simple, i think it has about 5 views in story board, and 1 view programmatically.

Comment: I'm thinking that I'm getting these warnings because i don't have a proper loading page for the database copy method..

Comment: I do absolutely no database work and get these errors so the database might not be the problem. Does the error still occur after you have pre-loaded the database?

Comment: Once the database is copied in the document folder of the app, the warnings rarely come up, maybe about 1/10 of the time.... but if it is coping the db, it's about 100% of the time.

Comment: The solution is probably to load it on a background thread. Is that possible in your case?

Comment: The database needs to be copied before the app can function. Would it be better to copy the database in the first view, instead of the app delegate ?